# In "Real Steel", what's the secret Max will keep for Charlie?

Tags: real-steel

At the end of the movie *[Real Steel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Steel)*, the following conversation takes place between Charlie (Hugh Jackman) and Max (Dakota Goyo):

> **Charlie Kenton:** Max, I.. I really want you to know. No, I need you to know, I...
> **Max Kenton:** Don't worry. Your secret's safe with me.
> **Charlie Kenton:** Wait. Wait.
> *[Charlie goes over to Atom, turns him on then walks over with Atom towards Max, picks Max up and puts him on his shoulder whilst the crowd cheers for them]*
>
> <sup>*Last lines in the movie, as found [here](https://transcripts.fandom.com/wiki/Real_Steel)*</sup>

What secret?

---

When searching for an answer on the Internet, I saw three possibilities mentioned:

1. Charlie wants to tell Max he loves him.
2. Charlie wants to tell Max that he is not really his father.
3. Charlie wants to tell Max that he thinks Atom is sentient.

But I'm open for other interpretations.

Comment: I only saw parts of this movie, so I may have missed an important part.

Comment: If you watch the "butterfly" deleted scenes (available on YouTube) it makes it clear that Max is definitely his son.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Early into the movie, when Max first activates Atom, cleans him and then plays around with him at night in the rain, he begins to feel an attachment to him, asks if he can understand him, and says "your secret's safe with me". Atom then goes on to fight for Max and not only win money, but inevitably forge the connection with his father that he never had.

Later on in the movie, when he says this same line to his father, it's paying homage to that former scene, because now Charlie is fighting for Max instead of Atom, both figuratively as a father and literally during the fight, which is what Max asked for after Charlie got beat up and tried to send Max to live with his legal guardians.

I missed this the first time I watched it as well, but after rewatching it, I was full of the feels.

Answer (score 6):

I'm pretty sure that Charlie is trying (in typically ham-fisted fashion) to tell Max that he loves him. Given that they're both **too damn manly** to actually say it, Max tells him that he knows it and that his father doesn't have to say it out loud, thus saving them both the embarrassment.

Comment: I thought so too, but the choice of words used by Max seems a bit... _off_, even if it reflects an earlier scene (that I missed) where Max said the same thing to Atom, after suspecting him to be sentient ("have a heart"). So maybe his father has a heart as well? That's the secret?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but I have a strong feeling that the secret mentioned two times is that the robot, Atom can watch, listen and understand things. He can also read the emotions.
That means, it's a sentient or something like that. As on IMDB, for the *Real Steel 2* storyline, it's mentioned that Atom can also feel.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is that at the start they show and tell you that Charlie fought the boxing world champion and was dancing with him. And on the end fight scene he seemed like he loved fighting and clearly was good enough to be the best but he lost the fight on purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Max never referred Charlie as "dad" earlier in the movie.. so when he does, Charlie replies in that matter to make sure that Max knows that he is not his biological father. Max´s answer is his way of saying "I know you're not my bio dad, but you are my dad".. or that Atom is a sentient.

Answer (score 0):

Having watched *Real Steel* numerous times, the comment at the end about the secret is safe with me is more than just connecting a line across the movie. I honestly think that  Charlie bet against Atom in the final fight as a means of making some money back. Charlie’s reaction in trying to tell him seems like he feels guilty.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that Charlie wants to tell Max that he is not really his father.

There's a scene when CCharlie asks Max his age and he looks confused, as if the years didn't match...